# Show that $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) $ does not exist.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

Let $f(z) =\frac{z}{\bar{z}} $. Show that $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) $ does not exist.

Solution:
Let $z= x + iy  $,  where $x$, $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $\bar{z} = x -iy$ is its conjugate and
$$f(z) = \frac{x+iy}{x-iy}$$

We take two distinct paths and show that each path gives us different limits. First, we let $z$ approach the origin along the real axis. Then,
$$ \lim_{(x,0) \to (0,0)} \frac{x+iy}{x-iy} $$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{x} $$
$$= \lim_{x \to 0} 1 = 1 $$

On the other hand, if we let $z$ approach the origin along the imaginary axis,
$$\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{z}{\bar{z}}= \lim_{(0,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x+iy}{x-iy} $$
$$= \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{-y}{y} $$
$$= \lim_{y \to 0} -1 = -1 $$

Since we have found two different limits of $f(z)$ as $z$ approaches 0, we have shown that $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z) $ does not exist.

Is there something that I need to revise?

Comment: You  forgot the square in $f(z)$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited it

Comment: Looks good, your proof is correct.