# Let $f(z) = \frac{x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi}{x^2 - y^2 - 2xyi } $. Does the limit of $f(z)$ exists as $z$ approaches the origin?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

Let $f(z) = \frac{x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi}{x^2 - y^2 - 2xyi } $. Does the limit of $f(z)$ exists as $z$ approaches the origin?

Comment: Yes, it is enough.

Comment: Note that $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{\bar z^2} = \left( \frac{z}{\bar z}\right)^2$, therefore this is closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4568915/42969.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the path $y=x$ is fine since it's a line. It's actually two paths, since you could use $\lim_{x \to 0^{-}}$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}$

More generally, you can use paths with $y$ equal to any continuous function of $x$, or $x$ equal to any continuous function of $y$, or $\theta$ equal to any function (not necessarily continuous!) of $r>0$. Of course, the path must actually approach the domain limit point: for example, to approach the origin with $x=f(y)$ and $f$ continuous, we need $f(0)=0$.

There's also parameterized paths, with $x=g(t), y=h(t)$ and considering the existence and value of $\lim_{t \to 0^{+}} f(g(t), h(t))$. If both $g$ and $h$ are continuous, that's a valid path (except in a strange case where $g(t)=h(t)=0$ for all $t \in (0,a)$ for some positive $a$).